# Storing list of strings in MySql column

Tags: sql, arrays, database, list, database-design

I have a *users* table which contains data for registered users, each row represents a user. One column in particular should contain a list of groups the user is part of, at the moment that column is of TEXT type and I'm storing that list as a string where groups are separated with a semicolon, something like:

```
admin;moderators;devteam
```

And I was wondering: "Is this a good idea?", is there a better/safer way to do this that doesn't require a lot of effort to implement or is this "ok"?
Here is a pic of the table as of now:
[image: users table]

Comment: It's fine assuming you never want to do any type of ordering, filtering, sql side value validation, or joining on those values. If you ever want any of those things then it would be recommended to refactor this to a set of tables in at least 3nf.

Comment: This is a many-to-many relation Users >--< Groups.  MySQL does not store lists (or arrays or other data structures (non-primitive types)  and hacking your own is a pain -- You will want a separate  table for users

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> And I was wondering: "Is this a good idea?"

Short answer: **probably not**.

**Why**

If you will ever need to do any manipulation on that column, you will find yourself in big trouble. Simply selecting all users in a group will require some operations on a string (usually not performance-friendly). Same will hold true for sorting, joining and all the other operations SQL is great for.

**Solution**

What you describe is a typical example of N:N relationship, where each user can belong to multiple groups and each group can have multiple users in it.

The 'standard' way of modeling this relationship is creating a new table, where each row will represent a user belonging to a group. The columns will be group and userID.

With data from your example

```
userID  | group
--------|----------
     1  | admin
     1  | moderator
     1  | test
```

This allows to have one row for each user in the `users` table, and getting the groups of a specific user is as simple as

```
select  group
from    user_groups
where   userID = '1'
```

Comment: Do I need junction tables for this? Could you please provide an example with some code?

Comment: this solution will work fine but in case of large amount of data,the size of the table will be more as we are having duplicate rows for userIds.
the answer should be in a way in which we can store all related values in a single row.
like: using list or json array